# How can I convert a dropdown selection to a custom object in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to create a simple View to create a new `Server`object. Here's the `Server` class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public partial class Server
    {
        public Server()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [Display(Name="Server Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Domain")]
        public Domain Domain { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the `Domain` class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Domain
    {
        public Domain()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String FullyQualifiedName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a `DropdownListFor` the domain in the Create.cshtml for the Server as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Domain.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.DomainItems, "Please select a domain", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This works great until I try and submit the form to be saved. It seems that the form is trying to save the selected Dropdown value to a new `Domain` object. Is there any way that I can override this and retrieve & set the `Domain` object in the `Server` manually?

Comment: Its setting the value of `Domain.ID` but because you have other `Required` properties in `Domain` it probably causing validation errors. You could use a view model that includes property `DomainID` and bind to that, then use the selected value to call the database to get the `Domain`

Comment: With the constructors you have in each class it means you can never have 2 instances of a class that have the same ID. That means that every time you retrieve some data from the database, or get submitted by a form or are instantiated in any way they will have a brand new id.

Comment: @Martin: I agree with [Ben Robinson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/253257/ben-robinson), but there is a work around when submitting the Form you will get FormCollection there you ll get old GUID which you can use, for that you ll have to use HiddenFor wigh Domain.ID and other, but it's a bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension method for dropdownlistfor as below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.DomainItems, "Please select a domain", new { @class = "form-control" })
```